# TypeError: Cannot call method "getDay" of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am jumping into a script that has been working for over a year - which has now started to post the TypeError: Cannot call method "getDay" of undefined.

I believe this is the function that is causing the issue - but not sure how to resolve:

```
function businessDaysBetween(startDate, endDate) {
  var dayDiff = endDate.getDay() - startDate.getDay();

  if (dayDiff < 0) {
    dayDiff = 5 + dayDiff;
  }

  return Math.floor((((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime())/1000/60/60/24/7) * 5) + dayDiff);
}
```

---

```
function sendReminderEmail() {
  try {
    //Open Google spreadsheet "New Hire - Notification", and retrieve "New Hire" sheet
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("is identified");
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("New Hire");
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    Browser.msgBox(e.message);
  }
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var currentDate = new Date(); 

  //Iterate through rows
  for (var i = 2; i <= rows; i++) {
    var hrngMgrComplete = sheet.getRange(i, sheet.getLastColumn());
    //Check if hiring manager has completed details form
    if (hrngMgrComplete.getValue() != "Yes") {
      var reminderDate = sheet.getRange(i, 13).getValue();
      var days = businessDaysBetween(reminderDate, currentDate);
      //check if last reminder was sent earlier than 3 business days or more 
      //from today.
      if (days >= 3) {
        var noOfReminders = sheet.getRange(i, 14).getValue();
        //Send appropriate email based on how many reminders have been received
        if (noOfReminders == 0) {
          sendFirstReminder(i);
        }
        else if (noOfReminders == 1) {
          sendSecondReminder(i);
        }
        else if (noOfReminders == 2) {
          sendHRNotification(i);
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

---

could it be *var currentDate = new Date();*

Comment: make sure your startDate and endDate are of type Date

Comment: Hi, can you include the code which is calling the businessDaysBetween method? Probably either startDate or endDate are undefined, this might be because they were initialized with an invalid date string if that is the case.

Comment: any thoughts on var currentDate = new Date();

Comment: It's not `var currentDate = new Date();`, that works fine. The function is fine too. It's almost certainly this `var reminderDate = sheet.getRange(i, 13).getValue();`. Do `console.log(typeof(reminderDate));` and see what you get.

Comment: thanks - I haven't worked with console.log - where should that be positioned in the script